# Составление запроса SQL с дополнительным условием

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Дано: Таблицы с которыми работаю **events** (события) и **photoreports** (фотографии).
С этимим все нормально (place_access, place_format,country, metrolist, place, citys, event_type, users)

Запрос для вывода события выглядит так:

```
SELECT * FROM (place_access, place_format,country, metrolist, place, citys, event_type, users) 
JOIN `events`   
ON(events.event_access = place_access.id)  
AND(events.event_place_id = place.place_id)  
AND(events.event_type = event_type.id)  
AND(events.event_format = place_format.id )  
AND(events.event_country = country.id )  
AND(events.event_city = citys.id )  
AND(events.event_metrolist = metrolist.id)  
AND(events.event_adder = users.id_user) WHERE `id_event`='1' LIMIT 1
```

По итогам я вижу событие с **ID = 1** и данные из смежных таблиц, так как данные в других таблицых фиксированные.  Список фотографий хранится в таблице **photoreports** где у фотографий столбец photoreport_event_id равно заданным **ID** из таблицы **events**.

Если я делаю запрос с JOIN по аналогии:

```
SELECT * FROM (place_access, place_format,country, metrolist, place, citys, event_type, users, photoreports) JOIN `events` ON(events.event_access = place_access.id) AND(events.event_place_id = place.place_id)AND(events.event_type = event_type.id) AND(events.event_format = place_format.id)AND(events.event_country = country.id) AND(events.event_city = citys.id)AND(events.event_metrolist = metrolist.id)AND(events.event_adder = users.id_user)AND(photoreports.photoreport_event_id = '1') WHERE `id_event`='1' LIMIT 1
```

Логично что условие соблюдается только при наличии изображения и наличия фотографии с заданным ID из таблицы events.

Если фотография есть, я вижу событие и могу вывести фотографию из photoreports, если фотографии нету я не вижу ничего включая само событие.

Как составить запрос так, чтобы событие выводилось в любом случае, а фотография только при наличии таких с ID события  из таблицы events. Если фотографии нету, то это как бы игнорируется и просто выводится событие по заданному условию.

В идеале задумано что при наличии фотографий  я смогу ее выводить так:
if ($ru->photo <> '') { $photo = 'код блока с картинкой'; } //Ну или как то так

Заранее спасибо.

Вопрос был решен

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте [внешнее соединение](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_explicit_join_operations.html). Если я правильно понял, то нужно просто заменить JOIN на RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: Да, вариант с переключения запроса с JOIN на RIGHT JOIN и нужен был.
Спасибо.

Однако теперь если фотографии есть все выводится как надо.
Если нету, то пропадают все данные из присоединенных таблиц.

Comment: Разберитесь с этой кучей:
(place_access, place_format,country, metrolist, place, citys, event_type, users, photoreports)
Пока они неявно соединяются (внутреннее соединение). Используйте явное (внешнее) соединение.

Comment: Если не затруднит можно пример хотя бы с одним столбцом?

Comment: Ниже я убрал из вашего списка таблицу place. Аналогично поступите с остальными.
SELECT * FROM (place_access, place_format,country, metrolist,citys, event_type, users) 
RIGHT JOIN `events`   
ON(events.event_access = place_access.id) 
RIGHT JOIN  place 
ON(events.event_place_id = place.place_id)

Comment: Спасибо. Выручили и дали новый опыт ))